# Fitting a function of a variable number of parameters and number of independent variables

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy-optimize

I am using curve_fit to fit a function of variable number of parameters and fixed in number but more than one independent variables

The fitted function (fun_multiple) takes the multiple independent variables as a array of arrays (alphas) and the fitted parameters are G and number of Hs parameters, which changes depending on the data given. Flux array is 1-D.

The fitted function is:

popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda alphas, G, *Hs: fun_multiple(alphas, G, Hs), self.alphas, flux, p0=[0.1, *self.max_mags])

Below is the example data for which 6 parameters is fitted (1xG plus 5xHs).

I am getting this error, which seems understandable, but i can not pinpoint what should be corrected?

File "/home/starlink/PCFit/PCFit_1.17/fitter.py", line 64, in fit_HG
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda alphas, G, *Hs: fun_multiple(alphas, G, Hs), self.alphas, flux, p0=[0.1, *self.max_mags])
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 742, in curve_fit
xdata = np.asarray_chkfinite(xdata, float)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 486, in asarray_chkfinite
a = asarray(a, dtype=dtype, order=order)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 102, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (5,) + inhomogeneous part.

flux [0.00366438 0.00398107 0.00401791 0.00452898 0.00465586 0.00452898
0.00436516 0.00428549 0.00416869 0.00366438 0.00331131 0.00301995
0.00304789 0.00299226 0.00280543 0.00263027 0.00263027 0.00246604
0.00253513 0.00199526 0.00201372 0.0021677  0.00222844 0.00233346
0.00235505 0.00235505 0.00248886 0.00253513 0.00258226 0.00260615
0.00267917 0.00272898 0.00277971 0.00299226 0.00316228 0.00343558
0.00353183 0.00224905 0.00218776 0.00199526 0.00201372 0.0021677
0.00222844 0.00233346 0.00235505 0.00235505 0.00248886 0.00253513
0.00258226 0.00260615 0.00267917 0.00272898 0.00277971 0.00299226
0.00316228 0.00343558 0.00353183 0.00359749 0.00390841 0.00398107
0.00343558 0.0030761  0.00299226 0.00258226 0.00246604 0.00233346
0.00224905 0.00218776 0.00199526 0.00201372 0.0021677  0.00222844
0.00233346 0.00235505 0.00235505 0.00248886 0.00253513 0.00258226
0.00260615 0.00267917 0.00272898 0.00277971 0.00299226 0.00343558
0.00353183 0.00359749 0.00390841 0.00398107 0.00343558 0.0030761
0.00299226 0.00258226 0.00246604 0.00233346 0.00224905 0.00218776
0.00199526 0.00201372 0.0021677  0.00222844 0.00233346 0.00235505
0.00235505 0.00248886 0.00253513 0.00258226 0.00260615 0.00267917
0.00272898 0.00277971 0.00299226 0.00316228 0.00343558 0.00353183
0.00359749 0.00390841 0.00398107 0.00343558 0.0030761  0.00299226
0.00258226 0.00246604 0.00233346 0.00224905 0.00218776]
alphas [array([ 3.5,  3.1,  2.8,  1.5,  1.4,  1.4,  2. ,  2.3,  2.6,  4.2,  7.2,
9.7, 10. , 10.2, 12.4, 15.9, 16.1, 17.3, 17.4]), array([17. , 16.2, 14.4, 13.5, 11.6, 11.3, 11. , 10.3,  8.8,  8.5,  8.1,
7.3,  6.9,  6.5,  5.7,  4.1,  2.4,  2. , 12.1, 13.8]), array([17. , 16.2, 14.4, 13.5, 11.6, 11.3, 11. , 10.3,  8.8,  8.5,  8.1,
7.3,  6.9,  6.5,  5.7,  4.1,  2.4,  2. ,  1.6,  1.2,  1. ,  2.5,
4.2,  4.6,  8.8, 10.3, 11.4, 12.1, 13.8]), array([17. , 16.2, 14.4, 13.5, 11.6, 11.3, 11. , 10.3,  8.8,  8.5,  8.1,
7.3,  6.9,  6.5,  5.7,  2.4,  2. ,  1.6,  1.2,  1. ,  2.5,  4.2,
4.6,  8.8, 10.3, 11.4, 12.1, 13.8]), array([17. , 16.2, 14.4, 13.5, 11.6, 11.3, 11. , 10.3,  8.8,  8.5,  8.1,
7.3,  6.9,  6.5,  5.7,  4.1,  2.4,  2. ,  1.6,  1.2,  1. ,  2.5,
4.2,  4.6,  8.8, 10.3, 11.4, 12.1, 13.8])]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Dagmara! Please take a look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will help you to ask questions in better way. Now it is hard to help you, because the question is not formatted and there are missing some parameters needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Let me guess: You have an array cantaining arrays. Maybe all cantained arrays must have the same length?

Comment: I had a list containing arrays. I have now sorted it out. It was due to lack of backwoods compatibility of some functions in scipy/numpy/python. In the never version curve_fit indeed requires homogeneous array of independent variables. Mine is not, but it was working under scipy 1.1.0 and python 3.7. After moving to python 3.8 and scipy 1.1.6 the code stoped working. So an easy solution was to go back to the old version of scipy. It would be nice to have back a possibility to have an inhomogeneous list of independent variables.